# Best way to name folders/files when using Dimensions such as inches?

Tags: file, naming, dimensions

Trying to find if there is a safe way to name files and folders while including dimensions in inches.

For example. I have many graphics (book covers) with different print dimensions.

4.25 x 7 Cover
0.50. in. Spine

So the file would look something like "HCGM2D-4.25x7-0.50.psd"

But how else could I name the file without using punctuation and still have it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

use the name like this "HCGM2D_4-25*7_0-50.psd"

i think that would work you fine

Comment: Is using the underscore on server reliable?